# Retrieve a Session by ID

Tags: jsp, session

Can we retrieve a session corresponding to a particular session ID?

I am getting session ID using

```
session.getId();
```

I want to retrieve the session corresponding to this ID.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: similar problem solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809792/how-to-get-a-session-by-session-id-in-jboss-5/55809794#55809794

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a SessionListener and store a map of the sessions sessionId->HttpSession.

Here is a code example of a SessionLisetener:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Servletsessionlistener.htm

Answer (score 0):

JSP provides couple of implicit objects and you can access without any additional effort: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij
So, if you want to access to your current session just use the following code:

```
session.getAttribute("name");
session.setAttribute("name",  "value");
```